# Special method __cmp__ doesn't work

Tags: python

The special work `__cmp__` doesn't work. Say the following code:

```
class Test():
      def __cmp__(self, other):
           return False

t1 = Test()
t2 = t1

print t2 == t1
```

I should get False because that the **cmp** is always returning False. But actually, python is printing True for me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This cannot possibly be real code, as `__cmp__` takes *two* parameters (self and other). If you had run it, you would get `__cmp__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, i have modified my question. i just missed the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Not sure why the votes to close, not a great question, but not off-topic either. I voted to keep open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__cmp__` should return `-1`, `0` or `1`, indicating of it's lower than, equal to or higher than `other`. Returning `False` will actually make it compare as equal to everything, as the integer value of `False` is `0`.

```
class Test():
      def __cmp__(self, other):
           return -1
```

Also note that `__cmp__` is deprecated and is ignored in Python 3. You should implement `__eq__` and the other so called [rich comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) instead.

Comment: Hi Lennart, i am using 2.6.2, and just using __cmp__ to learn the special method of Python. also, you are right, this method should take 2 parameters. i have updated my question.

Comment: Hi lenart, you are right. if let __cmp__ always return 1 or -1, i will get False by t1 == t2, on the opposite, if let the __cmp__ return 0 or False, will get True by t1 == t2.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Not only `t1 == t2`. `t1 == 'whatever'` will also return True. ;-)

Comment: yes, u are right. what i am wondering again, is why i am getting True via 0 == t1.

i think i should get False via 0 == t1. because 0 should be inherited from object, and the object.__cmp__ should be called here, and we should get False.

Comment: @Geoffrey - `int` doesn't have a `__cmp__`, it has a [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method, which when called with a not compatible type will *return* `NotImplemented` (as do many builtin types). In this case, the comparision is tried again with the order reversed.